# Prevent hardware from loading or consuming (battery) power?

Tags: bios, battery, battery-life

I'm using an Asus Zenbook UX32VD notebook and would like to maximize its battery life.

Would it be useful for me to disable devices that I do not use, such as the internal bluetooth device?

Also, how can I disable these devices entirely such that they do not consume power? As opposed to disabling it in the Windows device manager, which only causes the driver to not load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable permanently: uninstall and disable! That way it's never being called.

Whether you see any performance benefit, it really depends on how much hardware you're going to disable, coupled with things like screen brightness, what you're running etc. And what you're prepared to disable - for example, killing your wifi will save battery but I guess this would not be an option.

Comment: In the device manager I can only uninstall the driver. How would you uninstall the device such that it is never loaded by the BIOS?

Comment: If the OS doesn't call it (managed or not) then it won't consume it. If you are that concerned, and know what you're doing, you can remove this devices in some instances. Uninstall and disable in device manager - this will also stop it asking you to re-install on booting up!

Comment: Hmm, so what is the difference between disabling and uninstalling it in the device manager?

Comment: Uninstall removes the driver but the OS can still see it - therefore, upon reboot (for example) it will probably detect the new hardware and try to update/install the driver. Disabling tells the OS it's not to be used.

Comment: I tried to uninstall the Bluetooth device, but this has no effect. It keeps "finding new hardware" and thereby reinstalling the bluetooth device.

Comment: As I said, you need to disable it. I'm sorry, I did say uninstall but disable as well (or maybe instead of)